# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'

Tags: python, selenium, service

I am using python in VSCode and getting errors, I'm  starting to learn about selenium, I'm getting an error stating:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service



path = r'/Users/ashleyrabanales/Desktop/chromedriver' #f path 
driver_service = Service(executable_path= path) #set a driver for the path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service) # how to launch chrome auto
driver.get('https://estimize.com/')

driver.get('https://estimize.com/')
```

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'
```

Comment: What version of selenium do you use?

Comment: 3.141.0 is the version @EugenyOkulik

Comment: That's an ancient version released somewhere in 2017. Upgrade to the latest version (now it is 4.6.0) and be sure you use python version > 3.6